# Opening Quickbooks Online in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: integration, sharepoint-2013, quickbooks-online, popup-blocker

I am trying to open QuickBooks Online in SP 2013, as web-part, but gives me pop-up blocker messages for few times till the login page gets opened. After login, it also shows few pop-up message and then renders the main page. However, when I login to the QuickBooks Online page outside of SP, I won't get any such messages.

Due to pop-up blocker issue, I cannot see all information on some pages of the application within SP.

I am using IE10 and have the QuickBooks Online in the allow sites of the browser.

Is there a pop-up blocker in SP framework and how can I disable it?